# qTip2 hash navigation using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, hash, qtip2

Basically, I'm creating hash navigation to take users directly to a page header, listed as a link on hover.

I'm trying to pair `h1` elements on various pages with their children `span id` values. The `h1` text is the text displayed in each `href`, and the `span id` value is the hash for the url.

I'm using qTip2 to display the links under a "parent" li element, which takes the user to the page without a hash. I'm using `$.ajax` to fetch the `h1` and `span id` values. Source code is directly from the qTip2 website, which can be found [here](http://qtip2.com/guides#content.ajax.element).

This works great; what isn't working so great, however, is getting the hash values to match up with the `h1` text values.

The following code outputs everything but the hash perfectly. I'm given only one of the `id` values instead of all of them. I've successfully created an array with the `span id` values, but have no clue how to pair them up correctly with their `h1` parents to create the correct url for each link.

Here is the qTip code:

```
$('li.menu a').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: function(event, api) {
                var originalURL = $(this).attr('href');
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('href')
                })
                .then(function(url) {
                    var $wrap = $("<div></div>").append(url);
                    var titles = $wrap.find("#maincontent h1 > *").unwrap().wrap('<a href="' + originalURL + "#" + $wrap.find('span').attr('id') + '" />').parent();

                    api.set('content.text', titles);
                }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                    api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
                });

                return 'Loading...';
            }
        },
        position: {
            my: 'top center',
            at: 'bottom center',
            adjust: {
                y: 10
            }
        },
        hide: {
            delay: 1000,
            event: 'mouseleave',
            fixed: true
        }
    });
});
```

How do I pair up the values to create each link with the `h1` as the display text and the child `span id` value as the hash? I'm open to any suggestions.

UPDATE: Solution added to original question below:

```
$('#desktop ul li.menu a').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: function(event, api) {
                var $url = $(this).attr('href');
                var $title = $(this).text()
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                })
                .then(function(url) {

                    var $data = '';
                    var $headers = $(url).find('#maincontent h1');
                    $headers.each(function(){
                        if ($headers.length > 1) {
                            $data += '<a href="' + $url + '#' + $(this).children().attr('id') + '" class="' + $title + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a>';
                        }
                        else {
                            api.destroy(true);
                        }
                    });

                    api.set('content.text', $data);                     

                }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                    api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
                });

            return '<div class="navi-loading">Loading...</div>';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has this issue, or wants to implement my solution, here's what I did:

```
    $('#desktop ul li.menu a').each(function() {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: function(event, api) {
                    var $url = $(this).attr('href');
                    var $title = $(this).text()
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    })
                    .then(function(url) {

                        var $data = '';
                        var $headers = $(url).find('#maincontent h1');
                        $headers.each(function(){
                            if ($headers.length > 1) {
                                $data += '<a href="' + $url + '#' + $(this).children().attr('id') + '" class="' + $title + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a>';
                            }
                            else {
                                api.destroy(true);
                            }
                        });

                        api.set('content.text', $data);                     

                    }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                        api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
                    });

                return '<div class="navi-loading">Loading...</div>';
                }
            }
        });
    });
```